# Sugar CRM getting relation of a bean with a one to many association

Tags: php, sugarcrm

This is my code:

```
<?php

        if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');
        switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
            case 'GET': $req = &$_GET; break;
            case 'POST': $req = &$_POST; break;
            default:
        }

        echo ' 0 ';

        $focus = new m_formProcessor();
        $focus->retrieve_by_string_fields(array('name' => $req['formProcessor'] ));

        echo ' 1 ';

        echo $focus->id;


        echo ' 2 ';

        $focus->load_relationship('m_modules');

        echo ' 2.1.2 ';

        $list = array();
        foreach ($focus->m_modules->getBeans() as $m_module) {
            echo ' 2.2 ';
            echo $m_module->target;
        }

        echo ' 3 ';

        echo $focus->module->target;
        echo $focus->modules->target;
        echo $focus->m_modules->target;

        echo ' 4 ';
    ?>
```

I was following the blog on this page: http://developer.sugarcrm.com/2012/03/23/howto-using-the-bean-instead-of-sql-all-the-time/

but there seems to be an error in the foreach, any advice would help.

Comment: What errors are you seeing, and in what part of the code? Is there a specific message in the sugarcrm.log or php error log? If not an error, then can you describe the expected result and the result you're getting?

Comment: i updated this question with full details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337131/sugarcrm-cant-access-a-relation-of-two-modules